# Sending notifications with Firebase cloud function

Tags: javascript, firebase, push-notification, firebase-cloud-messaging

In order to use `Firebase Cloud Messaging` to later send notifications,
I am trying to write a cloud function called *sendNotification*;
and I meet a problem in the process. If possible, I would like to get some advice on how to deal with the issue; or maybe just have somebody point out a mistake I may be doing.

Here is the error message I get when running the command:

firebase deploy

```
⚠  functions[sendNotification(us-central1)]: Deployment error.
Function load error: Code in file index.js can't be loaded.
Did you list all required modules in the package.json dependencies?
Detailed stack trace: Error: Cannot find module 'serviceAccountKey.json'
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (module.js:476:15)
    ........
```

It may useful to say that the file *serviceAccountKey.json* is in the directory called *node_modules*, in other words not missing.
Here is the code in index.js:

```
const functions = require('firebase-functions');
const admin = require('firebase-admin');
var serviceAccount = require('serviceAccountKey.json');

admin.initializeApp({
    credential: admin.credential.cert(serviceAccount),
    databaseURL: 'https://myapp.firebaseio.com'
});

exports.sendNotification = functions.https.onRequest((req, res) => {
    let registrationToken = "abc123.........789xyz";
    var payload = {
        notification: {
          title: "NotifTit",
          body: "The good stuff."
        },
        token: registrationToken
    };

    admin.messaging().send(payload)
    .then((response) => {
        console.log("Successfully sent message: ", response);
    })
    .catch((error) => {
        console.log("Error sending message: ", error);
    })
});

Here is the contents of the package.json file:

{
  "name": "functions",
  "description": "Cloud Functions for Firebase",
  "scripts": {
    "serve": "firebase serve --only functions",
    "shell": "firebase functions:shell",
    "start": "npm run shell",
    "deploy": "firebase deploy --only functions",
    "logs": "firebase functions:log"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "firebase-admin": "~6.0.0",
    "firebase-functions": "^2.1.0"
  },
  "private": true
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You cannot load files from the `node_modules` folder, since that folder is ignored when uploading your functions.

Firebase dev Lauren Long [commented](https://github.com/firebase/firebase-tools/issues/784#issuecomment-392989219):

> But one thing to keep in mind is that the entire node_modules folder
>   is ignored during uploading of source code, so your package.json has
>   to contain all of your dependencies and cannot reference any files
>   inside of 'node_modules'. In other words, your functions should still
>   be able to work if you ran the following commands inside of the
>   functions folder:

```
rm -rf node_modules 
npm install
```

Comment: I am experimenting, but all this is not clear. There are 2 directories called node_modules one inside functions/ and  the other one at the same level, with different contents. Beside the serviceAccountKey.json file needs to be somewhere, otherwise I get an error at some point.

Comment: But I am not sure where this serviceAccountKey.json file is supposed to be. I only know that by putting it inside node_modules (the one at the same level as functions) I was able to get rid of one error.

Comment: When running: "firebase deploy"
Error: "Error parsing triggers: Cannot find module 'serviceAccountKey.json'"

Comment: Your files all need to be inside the functions folder.

Comment: OK, so in the current case where should I put serviceAccountKey.json?
Under the functions folder directly (at the top) or inside the  node_modules sub-folder? I think I already tried and it failed, but we'll see.

Comment: The functions folder.

Comment: Directly at the top of the functions folder? Let me try.

Comment: When I run the "firebase deploy" I get an error. Error: Error parsing triggers: Cannot find module 'serviceAccountKey.json'

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/184585/discussion-between-michel-and-jakesteam).